# How do you send mysqli errors to the main php error log using mysqli_report?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

In a nutshell, I would like to keep tabs on mysqli errors.  No matter where in the site...it would be great if they were written to a central log file.

I have a log file setup for php errors which works great already, but just for php errors.

```
php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log pathtoerrorlog
```

I am using (in my php template) the following:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR);
```

This properly displays mysql errors in the code as they happen.  Very nice, but I would like the option to write these to main error log as well.  Is this possible?

I tried adding this line of code before mysqli_report, but it didn't help:

```
ini_set('log_errors',1);
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: set error_reporting appropriately?

Comment: @Marc That is a circular answer

Comment: not really. you've told php where to log, but you haven't told it WHAT to log. error_reporting controls that.

Comment: @Marc So maybe I'm being dense...but would I enter for my error_reporting value?  My apache error reporting is set to show all errors except notices if that is the same thing?

Comment: try `E_ALL` and then dial it back if that logs too much.